# Codeigniter if in_array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm passing data from my controller to view, I have code in my view

```
foreach ($mapData as $map)
{
 echo $map['x'].';'.$map['y'].'<br/>';
}
```

And it prints me something like

```
5;5
6;6
7;7
```

Now, I am passing another data from my database as a two-dimensional array (i guess)
which looks like something like this

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [x] => 5
        [y] => 4
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [x] => 5
        [y] => 5
    )

)
```

I want to check if any of $map['x'] and $map['y'] exists in that array so I am doing (Don't know any other way because I need to check this in foreach loop)

```
if (in_array(array($map['x'], $map['y']), $array)) {
echo 1;
}
```

But it doesn't work and according to http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php it should work? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$mapData` instead of `$array`? (perhaps you just used it as an example)

Comment: No, $array is different array than $mapData.. I already have an answer, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [x] => 5
        [y] => 4
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [x] => 5
        [y] => 5
    )

)
```

should look like

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 5
        [1] => 4
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 5
        [1] => 5
    )

)
```

That means, `$array` (i.e. haystack) should not be an array with different indexing than neddle.

You are passing index `x` and `y` as haystack. But in needle you are just passing like `array(5,5)` or `array(6,6)` and so on.

According to doc, `in_array()` can compare

```
in_array( array(5,5), array( array(5,5), array(6,6) ) )
```

but not

```
in_array( array(5,5), array( array('x' =>5, 'y' => 5), array('x' => 6, 'y' => 6) ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

[`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) is working properly, it's just that you're comparing an array without keys to an array that has an `x` and `y` as keys for their values. Try giving our new array the corresponding keys and *then* comparing:

```
if (in_array(array('x' => $map['x'], 'y' => $map['y']), $array)) {
    echo '1';
}
```